# Hibernate: search for entities that contains a value in a set of enums

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, set, criteria

I have an entity similar to the following example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AIRPLANE")
public class Airplane {

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Color.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "AIRPLANE_COLORS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AIRPLANE_ID"))
    @Column(name = "AIRPLANE_COLOR")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_AIRPLANE_COLOR_ID")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Color> colors;    
    ...
}
...
public enum Color {
    WHITE, RED, BLUE
}
```

Where colors is a Set of enums, and I want to make a search for all entities Airplanes that contains the color RED in this set.

Can I make that with Criterias or should I use HQL queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to perform such query using Criteria in Hibernate. You just have to join `colors` and ask for its `elements` property (i.e. `colors.elements`).

`elements` is a keyword defined in Hibernate's `CollectionPropertyNames` class and you can access your enum value using it.

```
session.createCriteria(Airplane.class)
    .createAlias("colors", "colors")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("colors.elements", Color.BLUE))
    .list()
```

Answer (score 0):

The criteria API is useful to create queries based on a dynamic set of... criteria. For a static query, HQL is always more readable:

```
select a from Airplane a where :color member of a.colors
```

or

```
select a from Airplane a join a.colors color where color = :color
```

should do the trick

Comment: It's the same query as mine, except it doesn't have a select clause. I advise you to always have a select clause: it's clearer, and is mandatory if you want your query to be JPA-compliant, and thus portable.

Comment: The color attribute is a set.  Not quite the original question, but: how to write the query for airplanes with two colors? (Maybe red AND white for Wisconsin fans?  :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by JB Nizet, you can use `HQL` to get the results:

```
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Airplane as airplane inner join "
                + "airplane.colors colors where colors =:color");
        query.setParameter("color", Color.BLUE);

        List<Airplane> list = query.list();
        for (Airplane airplane : list) {
            System.out.println("->" + airplane.getColors());
        }
```

Comment: It should be `query.setParameter("color", Color.BLUE)`

Comment: Thanks JB, I tried with `setString` and that also worked, but `setParameter` is the correct way of doing. Updated my answer now.

Comment: Try using `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)`, and I doubt it will work by passing a String. It will if you pass the enum.

Comment: If I add `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)`, then `setParameter` is working fine but the `setString` is throwing error as `ERROR: ORA-01722: invalid number`

Comment: This code works well, thank you. Usually, I use EnumType.STRING for enum mapping because if somebody modify the order of the values in the enum, doesn't break anything in the database